# Optional Environment Variables with @Value in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

Using @Value for non-existing environment variable will cause an IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ENV_VAR' in string value "${ENV_VAR}".

For example:

```
@Autowired
public SomeClass(@Value("{ENV_VAR}") final String value) { }
```

How can I make this value optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a default value, and the Optional class (in JDK8).

```
@Autowired
public SomeClass(@Value("{ENV_VAR:#{null}}") final Optional<String> value) {
    value.ifPresent(/* do something */);
}
```

Comment: can we instead of {null} pass any other value of our choice and then directly use the env variable?